# Does 'commonly' modify a verb in this sentence from Walden?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

In the first chapter of [Walden](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/205), Thoreau writes:

> The most interesting dwellings in this country,
> as the painter knows, are the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages
> of the poor **commonly**; it is the life of the inhabitants whose shells they are,
> and not any peculiarity in their surfaces merely, which makes them
> picturesque; and equally interesting will be the citizen's suburban box, when his
> life shall be as simple and as agreeable to the imagination, and there is as little
> straining after effect in the style of his dwelling.

The word order caught my attention and I can't stop wondering
about this word order:

> The most interesting dwellings in this country,
> as the painter knows, are **commonly** the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages
> of the poor;[...]

1. Which word order of the two is more common in modern English? By modern I mean here after the year 1750.
2. Does placing an adverb so far away from the verb it modifies, as in Thoreau's sentence cited above, convey a different meaning when compared with placing it right after the verb?
   Does *commonly* modify the verb *to be* in Thoreau' sentence?

Comment: Why shouldn't it modify _poor_? They are commonly the dwellings of the poor, after all, and he's already said they're the most interesting.

Comment: It's standard to use a qualification like this at the end of a sentence where it has the effect of modifying the entire sentence. Although it is offset by a comma commonly. No idea about the statistical aspect of the question.

Comment: I agree: "commonly" is a modifier in the copular VP "are the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages of the poor commonly". Notice that it could be relocated to just after "are".

Answer (score 1):

I believe Thoreau is talking about the humble buildings, which are usually the buildings of the poor.

You can read it like this:

> *The most interesting dwellings are the most humble huts and cottages [that are] commonly of the poor . . .*

If that read is correct, the adverb is in one of the two places where it must be if it’s going to modify the prepositional phrase *of the poor*.

Answer (score 0):

Thoreau

> The most interesting dwellings in this country, as the painter knows, are the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages of the poor **commonly**;

John Smith

> The most interesting dwellings in this country, as the painter knows, are **commonly** the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages of the poor;

Thoreau's sentence uses "humble log huts and cottages of the poor commonly" as a parenthesis modifying "the most unpretending." This suggests that, of the most interesting and unpretending dwellings in this country, the most common examples are the humble log huts, etc.: it would, however, have helped if he had put a colon after "unpretending," and a comma before "commonly."

The man with no name

> The most interesting dwellings in this country, as the painter knows, are the most unpretending: humble log huts and cottages of the poor, commonly;

Your sentence, in repositioning the "commonly," eliminates the parenthetical function of that clause and suggests that all the most unpretending dwellings are humble log huts etc., and that these are commonly the most interesting.

It's a very fine distinction, as I am well aware. Nevertheless changes of word order can suggest subtle changes of meaning. It is the position of "commonly" which in Thoreau's version signals that the clause is parenthetical, rather than a continuation of the previous clause.

Comment: The most salient interpretation is that "commonly" is a modifier in the copular VP "are the most unpretending, humble log huts and cottages of the poor commonly". Notice that it could be relocated to just after "are" with no change of meaning.

Comment: I disagree (no surprise there, then). The “commonly” is in an unusual position, and would be a poor construction, if it meant what you say. Not what one would expect from Thoreau. I think my construal of it is a more reasonable explanation.

Comment: Adverbs only very rarely modify nouns, meaning that it can only be a modifier in the copular VP.